# Navigate to login page when session expires with AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I got a small issue when navigating back to the login page after the session expires. I have a link on my page to view the password using ajax, if the session does not expires, the "view password" link will be replaced by the password for a moment; otherwise, it will navigate to the login page. I use this javascript to check whether the seesion still exist or not

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $(document).bind("ajaxComplete", function(event, response, ajaxOptions) {
        if (response.getResponseHeader('SEESION_EXP') === '1') {
            self.location = _CONTEXT_PATH;
            return false;
        }

    });

});
```

The problem here is, the login page will be replaced into the password place for a moment before user is actually navigated to the login page. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just get a string that you may use it for validation at client side. For example, my link invokes a servlet which will return 'redirectLogin' as repsonse to client if session is expired. If reponseText equals 'redirectLogin', then use window.location.replace for navigating to the desired page

```
$('#id_of_link').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();   

            $.get('ActionServlet', function(responseText) { 

            if(responseText=="redirectLogin")
                window.location.replace("desired url");  
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check what is value of `response.getResponseHeader('SEESION_EXP')` if it is 1
then use `window.location = _CONTEXT_PATH;`